# Matlab script a(n)=a (n-1)+a (n-2)

Tags: matlab

How I make a script that check that my matrix do this condition? Also, how I get back the numbers of the rows and columns that do the condition?
Tnx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With n do you mean the row number? In that case if A is your matrix of size N by M, you could do it by

```
%initialize vectors for the indices you want to return
rows = nan(N*M);
cols = nan(N*M);

counter = 0
for i = 3:N
    for j = 1:M
        if A(i,j) == A(n-1, j) + A(n-2, j)
            counter = counter + 1;
            rows(counter) = i;
            cols(counter) = j;
        end
    end
end

% remove nans from end
inds = find(~isnan(rows));
rows = rows(ind);
cols = cols(ind);
```